# Color a polygon if its PARCEL_ID is found in a list of Parcel_ID's

Tags: qgis

I have a project with a layer of all the tax parcels in the town.
I have added a CSV data file with the PARCEL_ID's of a subset of all the Parcels.
I've done a JOIN of the PARCEL_ID field the parcels layer to the PARCEL_ID in the CSV file
I would like to add a conditional style to set the color of the parcels whose ID is found in the CSV file.

Is there some kind of IF PARCEL_ID is found in (the CSV file) set that parcel polygon color to some-color?

QGIS 3.26.1.
macOS Monterey.
Mac mini M1

Answer (score 2):

You can set this expression as a symbology rule on your Parcels layer

```
array_contains( 
    aggregate(
        'the_csv',             -- layer name of the csv (imported as delimited text layer)
        'array_agg',           -- aggregate values to an array
        "PARCEL_ID"),          -- the field in the CSV layer to aggregate
    "PARCEL_ID"                -- the field name in your `Parcels` layer
)                              -- the expression returns true if the current feature's parcel id is in the array
```

###### Steps to set the expression as a rule:

1. Double click the rule to edit it

[image]

2. Click the expression editor button

[image]

3. Enter expression - make sure to change the layer name and field name(s) accordingly

[image]

4. Click Okay to add the rule

###### If you need another rule to symbolise the features that don't match the expression:

5. Click the Back button to view the list of all rules

[image]

6. Add another rule using the [image] button near the bottom of the pane
7. Set it to *ELSE* to make a catch-all for all features that don't meet your first rule

[image]

Alternatively to *ELSE* you can add further rules with expressions to refine how the remaining features are symbolised.

Comment: Walk me through that a bit: In the Parcels Layer, go to Layer Styling, Symbology, and select Rule-Based from the Drop-down. Add Rule. Give it a name, and select the Function editor? Where do I enter that expression?

Comment: I added the steps to my answer.